# How to convert a limit of a sum (involving composite function) into a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I’m finding it hard to convert a limit of sum which involves a composite function into a definite integral. For normal functions we can make use of this definition $$ 
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f \left(
                                                           a+ \left(
          \frac{b-a}{n} \right) i 
                                               \right)= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

But let’s consider I have something like this: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} 
\frac{x}{n}\left[
\ln \Bigg(1 + \dfrac{x^2}{n^2} \Bigg) + \ln\Bigg(1+ \dfrac{4x^2}{n^2}\Bigg) + \ln\Bigg(1+ \dfrac{9x^2}{n^2}\Bigg) ... \ln\Bigg(1+ \dfrac{n^2x^2}{n^2}\Bigg) 
\right]$$ 
Well, the above thing is not of the standard form, because it can be written like $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln \left( 
                                                          1+ \left(\frac{ix}{n} \right) ^2 \right) $$ Where, in my opinion, $x/n$ is acting as $\frac{b-a}{n}$ but the problem is inside the argument we have $\left(\frac{b-a}{n} i \right)^2$ but according to the standard form we ought to have just $\frac{b-a}{n} i $.

I asked this to someone he said the above said limit can be written as the integral $$\int_{0}^{x} \ln(1 +t^2) dt$$ And I really don’t know how and it’s my question to know how.

There is one another example, how can I write $$\int_{0}^{x} \sin (t^2) dt$$ as limit of a sum? The most I can think is $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{n} 
\left[
\sin (x/n) + \sin(2x/n) .... + \sin(nx/n) \right]$$ but I know it’s equal to $$\int_{0}^{x} \sin (t) dt $$ Please help.

Comment: The formula in the beginning of your question works fine. Here you have $a=0,b=x$ and $f(t) =\log(1+t^2)$. Do you have any problem trying to guess values of $a, b, f$ from given sum?

Comment: Also don't confuse the $x$ in $x/n$ with the $x$ in $dx$. The $x$ occurring in sum is a constant.

Comment: Also for $\int_{0}^{x}\sin t^2\,dt$ use the formula in beginning with $a=0,b=x,f(t)=\sin t^2$. Its nothing more than plugging in a standard formula.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, now it seems obvious to me too but earlier I suspect that argument couldn’t be a function itself.

Comment: As you see in my $ln$ series example, the argument is itself a function.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest form of a riemann sum is 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right) = \int_0^1 f(u) du$$

Looking at the first example you gave, you can treat $x$ as a constant here. 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+ \left(\frac{r}{n} \right)^2 x^2\right)$$

here, $f(u) = \ln( 1 + u^2x^2)$. This expression becomes
$$x\int_0^1 \ln(1+u^2x^2) du$$
If we let $ux = t \implies xdu = dt$, then the integral becomes
$$\int_0^x \ln(1+t^2)dt$$

Taking the $\sin(t^2)$ example, to write it as a limit of a sum, you can try
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \sin\left(\left(\frac rn \right)^2 x^2 \right)$$
This simplifies to
$$x\int_0^1\sin(u^2 x^2)dx = \int_0^x \sin(t^2) dt$$
using the same substitution we made in the previous example.

Comment: But I suspect if we can write $$f(u) = ln (1+ u^2x^2)$$ beacuse according to the definition you have at first demands that argument must $\frac{r}{n}$, I want to know what will happen if the argument is itself a function?

Comment: @Knight: remember the definition of the Riemann Sums: $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname*{finest}\limits_{{\scr P}[a,b]}\sum\limits_{x_k\in{\scr P}}f(x_k)\Delta x_k$$ where ${\scr P}[a,b]$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. So as long as the partition created by the function is fine enough, it will approach the integral.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, that’s okay but $x_k$ must always be given as $a+ \frac{b-a}{n} k$

Comment: But in our situation we are having something like $x_k^2$.

Comment: @Knight: why *must* $x_k=a+\frac{b-a}n$? There is nothing in [the definition of the Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Definition) that says all the partitions must have equal width.

Comment: @robjohn Ah! Yes. But how $x_k$ affects the argument of $f$ in the integral? Please help.

Comment: What is the problem? The partitions in the answer *are* evenly spaced. Remember the function is $\sin\left(t^2\right)$

Comment: You can directly use the formula given in question with $a, b$ rather than its specialized version with $a=0,b=1$.